# A problem with the trunk of a regular pyramid with a square base

Tags: geometry

Please suppose we have the trunk of a regular pyramid with a square base.

The base has side of $8$ meters.

The smallest square, that is, the top surface of the square-based truncated pyramid, has side of $2$ meters.

The height of this solid is $4$ meters.

It is required to calculate the length of the internal diagonal, this means the length of the segment $PQ$ (see image).

[image]

I tried to use the Pythagorean theorem, determining the part of the base diagonal which constitutes the basis of the internal diagonal. The result in my opinion is that the part of the basic diagonal that is the basis of the internal diagonal, is $6\sqrt{2}$ meters long. The height, we know, is $4$ meters. Therefore:

$$\sqrt{(6 \sqrt{2})^2 + 4^2} = \sqrt{72 + 16} = \sqrt{88}$$

But my book says that the internal diagonal $PQ$ is $\sqrt{66}$ meters long.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much for considering my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualize this from the top by drawing both squares concentrically. The answer will be $\sqrt((4)^2$+ $(5\sqrt{2})^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be the projection of $Q$ onto the basis. Then $PH=5\sqrt2$, not $6\sqrt2$. To see why, consider that, after subtracting the projection of the upper diagonal from the base diagonal, you are left with two equal segments of $3\sqrt2$.